# How can I efficiently design a method where each condition is dependent on another condition?

Tags: c++

I have a method that needs to retrieve a type of size so for example I need a string to be returned that says "small", "medium" or "large".

So I call `GetSize(int size)`. But I also need to know how I want to return the size, do I want to return "small" or do I want to return "s".  So the method grew to `GetSize(int size, enum format)`.

Now I could do a switch case but it would be

```
switch (size)    
 {    
    case SMALL_SIZE:  
       switch(format)  
          case format::short  
          case format::long  
 }
```

So I would have to do a switch case inside every case for "size".  I could also break it down and call a method to get the format on every size case.

This seems like a lot of work, and I only have 3 cases of sizes here but imagine it was 10 cases for something else.  Are my solutions best or is there a better way?

Comment: what about a map<pair<int,format>,string> or similar?

Comment: This will depend on what action is actually taken in each `case format::X`. If there's a rule, then you're likely to be able to factor. If everycase is specific that will be harder. Try to provide more insight on what the method does (with more code ideally).

Comment: what about two different functions? `GetSizeShort(int size)` and `GetSizeLong(int size)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that your method can be replaced by a simple two-dimensional array.

```
// Use actual sizes in the declaration below
static string FormattedSize[2][2] = {
    {"small", "s"}
,   {"medium", "m" }
//  and so on...
};

string GetSize(int size, enum format) {
    return FormattedSize[size][format];
}
```

Comment: would it be more efficient to use a map with a pair as the key?

Comment: @Pittfall Generally, it is nearly impossible to beat an array at efficiency. However, in this case it absolutely does not matter: with only ten items to search, you wouldn't notice any difference unless you call this function billions of times in a really tight loop.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do something along the lines of:

```
switch(true) {
 case ((size == SMALL_SIZE) && (format == format::short)):
 case ((size == MEDIUM_SIZE) && (format == format::short)):
  return "s";
  break;
 case ((size == LARGE_SIZE) && (format == format::short)):
 case ((size == SMALL_SIZE) && (format == format::long)):
  return "m";
  break;
 case ((size == MEDIUM_SIZE) && (format == format::long)):
 case ((size == LARGE_SIZE) && (format == format::long)):
  return "l";
  break;
}
```